# WSO2 IS change password policy error message

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Iam trying to change error message for askPassword task (identity_mgt.events.schemes.passwordPolicy.properties.errorMsg)
I found that it could be done with editing file /repository/resources/conf/default.json. But it can't recognize Cyrillic symbols.
Is there any way to use cyryllic symbols symbols in this case?

Comment: Problem solved by adding to resources.properties records, where key - error message in latin, value - error message in cyrillic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the error keys and values to the `resource.properties`. Also for more advanced use case refer to the docs below.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Localization+Support+in+Identity+Server#LocalizationSupportinIdentityServer-ConfiguringLocalizationforAuthenticationEndpoints
[2] - https://medium.com/@akilam_38329/language-localization-in-wso2-identity-server-by-a-browser-click-10d6b11e5fd7